# PHP/MySQL Limiting characters outputted from a field

Tags: php, mysql

When I get a database array, sometimes there is fields with too much data for my results list page, which is suppose to give just a short description. How do I limit the characters count to something like 100.

This is my array for the loop:

```
<?php
    $i = 1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
```

This is my echo statement:

```
<?php echo $row['description']; ?>
```

Comment: Use `substr()` in PHP or MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`substr`](http://www.php.net/substr) like this:

```
<?php echo substr($row['description'], 0, 100); ?>
```

But it might be better—depending on your application needs—to do the limiting when making the initial MySQL query using [`SUBSTR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) which behaves the same way, but in MySQL.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(example_field, 1, 100)
FROM example_table
WHERE example_field IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
;
```

That MySQL script basically means return the substring of `example_field` starting from the first (`1`) character and going `100` characters in.

This might be better in some cases since if you are limiting text length to 100 characters, why grab the data for fields that might have 1,000+ characters? That would definitely bog down your PHP script in many cases. Handling that in MySQL is the best way to nip it in the bud if your app just needs 100 characters returned.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I did that earlier and I got a php error, I must have formatted it wrong.

Comment: Actually I just noticed sit is outputting random strings, not the first 1-100, but I see you just updated your answer.

Comment: Ya that works. But does changing the select statement instead of echoing make it less taxing on the CPU and Memory?

Comment: thanks its good to know because I'm really trying to learn about all aspects of building an data-driven site.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with substr()

```
<?php echo substr($row['description'],0,100); ?>
```

OR

```
function truncate($input, $maxWords, $maxChars)
{
    $words = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
    $words = array_slice($words, 0, $maxWords);
    $words = array_reverse($words);

    $chars = 0;
    $truncated = array();

    while(count($words) > 0)
    {
        $fragment = trim(array_pop($words));
        $chars += strlen($fragment);

        if($chars > $maxChars) break;

        $truncated[] = $fragment;
    }

    $result = implode($truncated, ' ');

    return $result . ($input == $result ? '' : '...');
}
```

// try with cuctom function truncate() , it help to cut description by words.

```
 <?php echo truncate($row['description'],5,200); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already put Jakes answer up. But since I am really just trying to learn, what are the pros and cons to this method over JakeGould answer because it seems like a lot more code?

Comment: substr() is a default function of php. I will explain with example, if description is "This is a boy" then substr("This is a boy",0,6) ; will print "This i" only. But truncate is a a custom function and  truncate("This is a boy",2,50) ; will print "This is...". In substr() text broken with "i" not printed "is" fully (Second word)

Comment: If you using substr() make sure syntax is correct. "0" is t the second parameter and "100" is the third parameter .    substr($row['description'],0,100); Please go through the syntax. http://www.php.net/substr

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers, you should use `substr`, but you can use it in combination with [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos) so that when you shorten the string, you stop after a complete word instead of interrupting a word itself.

```
$pos = strpos($row['description'], ' ', 100);
echo substr($row['description'], $pos);
```

Comment: did not see your answer, thought you were done for the night, I voted it up anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the SQL query. It's better to limit the results returned which reduces I/O and network throughput by not returning data from the database you're not going to use. In your SQL query do:

```
SELECT LEFT(description, 100) AS description
      ,....
FROM ...
```

Comment: Weird, `SUBSTR(example_field, 1, 100)` doesn't work for me, but using your answer does via `left`. My row is type: `mediumtext NULL`... Anyways, I hope `LEFT` isn't going to be a performance issue compared to the substr version.  Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is interested in another code snippets on how to limit character output with dots, I use this and it works well for me

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR(<column_name_here>, 1, 100),'...... Read More') AS Column_Name
```